# Java Arraylist size

Tags: java, arraylist, size

I'm having an issue understanding the output of size() for a "nested" ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>> myEmpls = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> dummy2 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dummy = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        myEmpls.add(dummy2);
    }

    System.out.println(myEmpls.size());

    // returns 4 as expected

    System.out.println(myEmpls.get(0).size());
    System.out.println(myEmpls.get(1).size());

    // both return 0 as expected

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        myEmpls.get(0).add(dummy);
    }
    System.out.println(myEmpls.get(1).size());

    // returns 10 altough I added to myEmpls.get(0) and not 
    // myEmpls.get(1) so I expected this to still be 0.
```

Can someone explain why this is the case? Maybe I am missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't all the dummy2s the same?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I actually ran into the same issue before but since I havent been coding for some time I failed to recognize it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding same reference of `dummy2` to all four positions of `myEmpls`. Therefore when you access any of them, you access same object as having variable `dummy2`, which really has 10 objects in it, because you added it in it.

You can even do this and it also returns 10

```
System.out.println(dummy2.size());
```

---

If you do this

```
for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
    myEmpls.add(new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>());
}
```

It would behave as you expected

Answer (score 1):

`myEmpls.add(dummy2);` add the same `ArrayList` instance to `myEmpls` muptiple times.

Therefore, calling `myEmpls.get(0).add(dummy)` adds elements to the same `ArrayList` instance referred by `myEmpls.get(1)`. Therefore the `size()` of `myEmpls.get(1)` is 10, since `myEmpls(0)==myEmpls(1)`.

If you change your first loop to :

```
for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
    dummy2 = new ArrayList<>();
    myEmpls.add(dummy2);
}
```

each element of `myEmpls` will be distinct, and `myEmpls.get(1).size()` would return 0 as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you have created an ArrayList object (`dummy2`) and then added that exact object to the list 4 times. Therefore, when you add to `dummy` to the object from `myEmpls.get(0)`, you are adding dummy to the other 3 indexes too as they are all the same object. Hence, the size is 10. Each index inside myEmpls points to exactly the same address in memory and therefore whatever you do to one of the indexes, you do to all of the others.

Answer (score 1):

List keeps the reference of `Object` added in it,change in state of `Object` reflects to all the references added in the *list* in your case.

***ForExample :***

```
    ArrayList<List<String>> mainList =new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> test1 =  new ArrayList<>();
    mainList.add(test1);
    mainList.add(test1);
    mainList.add(test1);
    mainList.add(test1);

    System.out.println(mainList);

    test1.add("Hello");//now add item to test1

    System.out.println(mainList);
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
[[], [], [], []]
[[Hello], [Hello], [Hello], [Hello]]
```